# How to detect current slide in swiper js?

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

Working with swiper js for a slider and want to detect the current image/slide. how i can detect with HTML and JS? any idea?

```
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper" align="center">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="images/card_gold.png" width="80%" align="middle" onclick="desc(\'' + card1 + '\')">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="images/card_platinum.png" width="80%" align="middle" onclick="desc(\'' + card2 + '\')">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="images/card_silver.png" width="80%" align="middle" onclick="desc(\'' + card3 + '\')">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add Arrows -->
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What information exactly do you want to have from the current image/slide?

Comment: http://www.idangero.us/swiper/api/#.VhJDi_mqpHw


In this page we can use 

> mySwiper.activeIndex

Index number of currently active slide

Note, that in loop mode active index value will be always shifted on a number of looped/duplicated slides



to get the index of current slide. thank you everyone :)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

its very easy. just use this:

```
swiper.activeIndex
```

Comment: This is the correct and recommeded answer as it uses Swiper to determine the current slide and not some external css class that might not yet have been assigned.

Comment: As a note: this value will be 1-indexed and *not* 0-indexed.

Comment: The thing to note is the returned value is zero-based... so if your first slide is active the return value will be 0, if it's slide 5, return value would be 4.

Comment: It should be noted that `swiper.activeIndex` does not match `data-swiper-slide-index` present on the slide. For that you should use `swiper.realIndex` as mentioned below.

Comment: This seems to be the working answer for swiper v5.x

Answer (score 18):

Expanding on the answers that already refer to the `realIndex` property, here is a method for fetching the current slide's element by using `realIndex` as well as the `slides` property (an array containing all slides of the instance) to get the slide-element:

```
let index_currentSlide = instance_swiper.realIndex;
let currentSlide       = instance_swiper.slides[index_currentSlide]
```

You can make use of this when constructing the instance by (for example) fetching the current slide whenever the `slideChange` event occurs and manipulating the element:

```
const instance_swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
  on: {
    slideChange: function () {
      const index_currentSlide      = this.realIndex;
      const currentSlide            = this.slides[index_currentSlide]
      //
      currentSlide.style.background = "red";
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: BTW, the instance is bound to `this` within the context of the event handler method, so you don't have to hard-code the variable name: e.g. `this.readIndex`.

Comment: @Tim thanks for pointing it out. So I can take out the first variable declaration and reduce it to `const currentSlide = this.slides[this.realIndex]`, right?

Comment: You can replace `instance_swiper` with `this` inside the `slideChange` method.

Comment: Not true. `activeIndex` should be used with `slides`. `realIndex` is only useful when you want to know which slide is active (the 1st one, the 2nd one, etc.)

Answer (score 17):

As of May 2016 they have added the realIndex property!

```
swiper.realIndex
```

https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/pull/1697

**Notice:**

- property is returned as a string
- property starts with 0, unlike
  activeIndex in loop mode which in my case started with 1

Answer (score 9):

As far as I can see from their demos, the current slide always has the `.swiper-slide-active` class on the current slide element.

You can use jQuery selectors to get properties from the active slide. Here's an example of me fetching its image source:

```
$('.swiper-slide-active img').attr('src')
```

Comment: Not recomended.

Comment: @MohammadAyoubKhan, you need to say why or your comment doesn't add value.

Comment: @michel-carroll The question is "How to detect current slide in swiper js?", There is an official API for this. We don't JQuery for this. Secondly, your answer not solving the problem.

Answer (score 4):

That's how **@Timsta** solution can be used:

```
import { Swiper } from "swiper/react";

// state that has the current active index, which can be used to force re-rende other components
const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);
    

// Trigger active index state update
<Swiper onRealIndexChange={(element)=>setActiveIndex(element.activeIndex)}>
   {children}
</Swiper>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using React.js here is how you could get activeIndex:

```
const swiperRef = useRef(null)
console.log(swiperRef.current.swiper.realIndex)

  const [currentSlide, setCurrentSlide] = useState(0);

  const [isLeftDisabled, setIsLeftDisabled] = useState(true);
  const [isRightDisabled, setIsRightDisabled] = useState(false);

  const updateIndex = useCallback(
    () => setCurrentSlide(swiperRef.current.swiper.realIndex),
    []
  );

// Add eventlisteners for swiper after initializing
  useEffect(() => {
    const swiperInstance = swiperRef.current.swiper;

    if (swiperInstance) {
      swiperInstance.on("slideChange", updateIndex);
    }

    return () => {
      if (swiperInstance) {
        swiperInstance.off("slideChange", updateIndex);
      }
    };
  }, [updateIndex]);


<Swiper
        className="swiper swiper-17-1"
        modules={[Pagination]}
        pagination={{
          type: "fraction",
        }}
        slidesPerView={1}
        ref={swiperRef}
      />
```

**Key thing is you need to clean up evenlistener!!!!**

Answer (score 1):

Here's a straightforward solution to this using `onActiveIndexChange`.

Using NextJs refs doesn't work. I highly recommend this approach if you are using SSR.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import type { Swiper as SwiperType } from "swiper";

const SwipeComponent: React.FC = () => {
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState<number>(0);

  const updateIndex = (swiperInstance: SwiperType) => {
    if (swiperInstance === null) return;
    const currentSlide = swiperInstance?.activeIndex;
    setCurrentIndex(currentSlide)
  }

  return (
    <section className="mb-32 mx-16">
      <Swiper
        initialSlide={currentIndex}
        onActiveIndexChange={updateIndex}
      >
     <SwiperSlide>
     ...
     </SwiperSlide>
   </Swiper>
  </section>)
}
```